# IIS Recycling issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, pool, recycle, application-start

I got an issue with IIS and recycle. I explain what we want, and what we did.

**What We want:**
we have an ASP.net WebSite, it executes a code in "Application_Start" which loads in memory a lot of data. It take few minutes. Then, we want to start the Application Pool automatically early morning, and the application pool keeps opened all the day.

**What We Did:**
With a scheduled task, we launch this line in a .bat at 07AM:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://xxxxxx

We configured the application Pool like that:
Recycling conditions at fixed Intervals: 720minutes
Idle TimeOut: 700 minutes

**What it does:**
At 07AM, the pool is started. it works fine all the morning.
And the pool recycled between 12PM and 2PM everyday. And it restarts without any connection by people. Alone.

With the 720minutes, it should restart only from 7PM, no?

We are in IIS 7.5 and windows Server 2008

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Enable IIS application pool recycle event logging and see why it recycles. If between 12PM and 2PM you see no such event, then likely the pool crashes instead of recycling and you need to debug the crash instead.

Comment: I enabled the log, and I get this log: A worker process with process id of 'xxxxx' serving application pool 'xxxxx' has requested a recycle because the worker process reached its allowed processing time limit.

Comment: the log is at 01:35PM